# SUM function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetJobInfo]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId, dbo.EmployeeJobs.ComputerCodeId, 
        FirstName, LastName
    FROM 
        dbo.Employees
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.EmployeeJobs ON dbo.Employees.EmployeeId = dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId 
    WHERE
        dbo.EmployeeJobs.ComputerCodeId IN (7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)
END
```

This is my current stored procedure, it all functions correctly so far. I have a property for my `employeejobs` table called `RegularHours`. I need to go through the jobs that I was returned and for each employee I need to add up the `regularHours` from all the jobs. I was looking at the sum function but couldn't get it to work.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Do I need to create a array property and set all the jobs to that before continuing?

Comment: Don't quite really understand your requirement. You wanted to change this `Stored Procedure` to return `RegularHours` ? Please post some sample data and show what is the required result

Comment: Sum only works with group by. You need to group your records. Do you want one record per Employee, or one record per Employee and ComputerCodeID combination?

Comment: Sorry for the poor wording on this. I need a separate sum for the total regular hours worked by each employee. So I believe I need to group by employeeId and get the sum for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this is what you are looking for

```
Select E.EmployeeId, EJ.ComputerCodeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName, SUM(EJ.RegularHours) as RegularHours
From dbo.Employees E
    INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeJobs EJ ON E.EmployeeId = EJ.EmployeeId 
Where EJ.ComputerCodeId in (7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)
Group By E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName, EJ.ComputerCodeId
```

Comment: that isn't giving me the sum though. its just giving me the regular hours for each job. I'm assuming its because were grouping by all 4 properties instead of just the employeeId. is there any way to only group by the EmployeeId?

Comment: Column 'dbo.EmployeeJobs.ComputerCodeId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. im getting that error if I try to only group by EmployeeId. Any help on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery. This will return the sum of hours of the employee for all the jobs and not only for the job on the result :

```
Select E.EmployeeId, EJ.ComputerCodeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName, 
       (Select Sum(H.RegularHours) 
        From EmployeeJobs H 
        Where H.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeID and
              H.ComputerCodeId in (7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)) as RegularHours
From dbo.Employees E
    Inner Join dbo.EmployeeJobs EJ on E.EmployeeId = EJ.EmployeeId 
Where EJ.ComputerCodeId in (7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)
```

Subqueries have a simple syntax but they are not very efficient. You can optimize its execution using a CTE (Common Table Expression) :

```
with H as (
  Select EmployeeID, Sum(RegularHours) as RegularHours
  From EmployeeJobs
  Where ComputerCodeId in (7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)
)
Select E.EmployeeId, EJ.ComputerCodeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName, H.RegularHours
From dbo.Employees E
    Inner Join dbo.EmployeeJobs EJ on E.EmployeeId = EJ.EmployeeId 
    Inner Join H on H.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId 
Where EJ.ComputerCodeId in (7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)
```

Comment: dancingfools answer was what I was looking for but thanks for your help.

Comment: @brock on your comment to his answer you said that it wasn't what you were looking for, that you need all the hours of the employee and not only the hours of each job. This is what I have written here for you. Anyway I'm glad that you have solved your problem.

Comment: @brock By the way, if dancingfolls answer has solved your problem, you should accept its answer to let it know.

Comment: so sorry, thought I had.